# Plot rows in pandas dataframe with marker label

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

[image]I have a DataFrame like the one below:

```
df = 

sample_number    data_point_1    data_point_2   data_point_3     sig_point
   1                0.10             0.15           0.29            0.20
   2                0.50             0.54           0.71            0.62
   3                0.25             0.32           0.51            0.45
   4                0.17             0.27           0.34            0.30
   5                0.65             0.51           0.71            0.62
   6                0.49             0.62           0.69            0.64
```

I would like to plot a given row for a `sample_number` across `data_point_1`, `data_point_2` and `data_point_3` as a line plot, along with a marker 'x' at the `sig_point`.

How would I do this for (1) a single row in the DataFrame and (2) multiple rows in the DataFrame (using a for-loop like `for index, rows in df.iterrows():` where I plot multiple rows (`sample_numbers`) with a legend and a marker at each `sig_point`?

Answer (score 1):

What you want would be possible with monotonic data, with non-monotonic data (e.g. sample 5 / purple curve) this would fail:

```
tmp = df.set_index('sample_number')
tmp2 = tmp.filter(like='data_point')
ax = tmp2.T.plot(marker='o')

xs = np.array([np.interp(tmp.loc[i, 'sig_point'], tmp2.loc[i], np.arange(tmp2.shape[1])) for i in tmp.index])

ax.plot(xs, tmp['sig_point'], marker='x', ls='', color='k')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: For example, for `sample_number = 1`, I want a line plot for data_points 1-3 and a market at the `sig_point` = 0.20. I don't want a scatter plot like you showed above.

Comment: The different colors in the legend should correspond to the different sample_numbers, not data_point_X

Comment: Please edit your question with a schematic of the expected output for clarity. Also check the edit.

Comment: I want to plot the first row for sample_number_1 as a line plot. On the same line plot, plot an X at `sig_point=0.20'. You're showing above how to plot each column, I'm referring to plotting each row. Each sample has 3 data points, which I want to plot.

Comment: Please provide the mockup output as requested

Comment: See picture above.

Comment: I see, however the values per line are not monotonic, it's not easy to find a unique intersection point

Comment: Could you explain why this doesn't work when it's not monotonic? If I'm just wanting to label a point (`sig_point`) on a line.

Comment: If you look at the purple line, there are 2 intersection points for `y = 0.62`.

Comment: Got it. Is there a way to specify labeling the first occurence of `sig_point` to resolve that?